# How to add shaders mods in opera GX

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, opera

I dunno nothing about adding shaders is opera GX mods
i make my own sooo i wanna add but i have to, i should add code in opera.css or should paste code in txt file
piece of that code looks like

`vec3 deform( in vec2 p, in float t ){
t *= 2.0;

```
p += 0.5*sin( t*vec2(1.1,1.3)+vec2(0.0,0.5) );

float a = atan( p.y, p.x );
float r = length( p );

float s = r * (1.0+0.5*cos(t*1.7));

vec2 uv = 0.1*t + 0.05*p.yx + 0.05*vec2( cos(t+a*2.0),  
                                         sin(t+a*2.0))/s;

return texture( iChannel0, 0.5*uv ).xyz;}
```

`
so pls help me out

i try to use shader in txt file by that i mean i found code in https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xsf3Rn and put in txt file | before i put there code form shadertoy there was a code for old shader